# What kind of SQL Server datatype should be used?

Tags: sql, sql-server

What datatype in SQL Server should be used to store 800 decimal values (0000-9999) in one row. Something like this:

```
0144,0152,0142,0136,0149,0147,0143,0123,0121,0128,0134,0139,
```

Is there any array in SQL Server?

Thank you!

Comment: Just don't or use json

Comment: Why do you want to store 800 decimal values in one row? If you are using SQL Server, perhaps a normalized design would be more appropriate?

Comment: Depending on what your requirements are you can store them in a `varchar` column as a json array or a normalised table as rows if you ever need to search, aggregate etc.

Comment: *"What data type in MSSQL should be used to store 800 decimal values (0000-9999) in one row."* None. You should have a `int` column that stores 800 decimal values in **800 rows**.

Comment: There is no array-type in MSSQL because that would result in denormalized data (though I do agree it would be convenient in many cases).

Comment: Why do some of the numbers in your sample data have leading-zeroes? Are the leading zeroes significant? If so, then you should not be using a numeric type.

Answer (score 2):

Normally you would use a separate table with a [SMALLINT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/int-bigint-smallint-and-tinyint-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) to store multiple values.

If you want to store them as a single column value, use VARCHAR(MAX) and store JSON, or store them as a byte array in VARBINARY(MAX).  If you store them as VARBINARY(MAX) SQL Server won't be able to query the individual values, and you'll have to fetch the blob back to your application to do anything with the individual values.